# How to remove double quotes from json_extract_array

Tags: google-bigquery, gis, apache-superset, legacy-sql

I have a set of coordinates that need to be in Geojson format but without the double quotes, i am also limited to select only on this dataset.
this line of code

```
json_extract_array(st_asgeojson(st_makeline( array_agg(st_geogpoint(locs.lon, locs.lat) order by locs.date))),'$.coordinates') as geo
```

gives me this

```
[
  "[-8.6359,40.6371716666667]",
  "[-8.63589166666667,40.637165]", 
  "[-8.63589333333333,40.6371583333333]", 
  "[-8.63589,40.637165]", 
  "[-8.63588833333333,40.6371716666667]", 
  "[-8.635885,40.6371766666667]", 
  "[-8.63588166666667,40.63718]"
]
```

i need it to be like this instead

```
[
  [-8.6359,40.6371716666667],
  [-8.63589166666667,40.637165],
  [-8.63589333333333,40.6371583333333],
  [-8.63589,40.637165],
  [-8.63588833333333,40.6371716666667],
  [-8.635885,40.6371766666667],
  [-8.63588166666667,40.63718]
]
```

Comment: using your example  - I actually see the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVzHB.png) you expected

Answer (score 3):

Ok i found the answer, in case some one else has the same issue.
use json_extract instead of json_array_extract.this will remove the double quotes

```
json_extract(st_asgeojson(st_makeline( array_agg(st_geogpoint(locs.lon, locs.lat) order by locs.date))),'$.coordinates') as geo
```